# Unable to fetch the jira cloud assets through atlassian-python-api

Tags: python-jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk, atlassian-python-api

I am working on a Atlassian Jira cloud product. I have a requirement to get the details of Jira cloud assets and update a field with some specific key-value pair. To achieve same, I have chosen python api to interact with Atlassian jira cloud and do those changes.

But, I am unable to access jira cloud assets using the `atlassian-python-api` which I have got from the https://pypi.org/project/atlassian-python-api/. Even I tried with different versions of it to achieve same.

Here is my sample code.

```
from atlassian import Jira

# Enter your Jira Cloud site URL and API token
JIRA_URL = "https://<your-domain>.atlassian.net"
JIRA_API_TOKEN = "<your-api-token>"

# Initialize the Jira API client
jira = Jira(
    url=JIRA_URL,
    username="",
    password="",
    cloud=True,
    api_token=JIRA_API_TOKEN,
)

# Fetch a list of all assets
assets = jira.assets().search("")

# Print the asset details in a tabular format
print("Asset ID\tAsset Type\tName\tDescription")
for asset in assets:
    print(f"{asset['id']}\t{asset['type']}\t{asset['name']}\t{asset['description']}")
```

But, getting below error.

```
 assets = jira.assets().search("")
AttributeError: 'Jira' object has no attribute 'assets'
```

After that, I tried to fetch with different components like - `jira.jira_service_desk().get_all_assets()` , `jira.get_all_assets()` and `jira.cloud.asset_management.get_all_assets() . But, everytime I am facing respective issue like` 'Jira' object has no attribute <>`.

Could you please suggest a way make the bulk operations on jira-cloud-assets.

FYI, Even I went with the atlassian provided api - https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/assetsapi/rest/api-group-assets/#api-asset-get - It also doesn't help to get them.

Expecting a solution to make write operations on Jira-Cloud assets.

Answer (score 2):

I once have the same problem. After I trace codes of the library. It is not documented on the atlassian python API website.

The APIs you seek are in `Insight`. Here is the [link](https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api/blob/master/atlassian/insight.py) to the source file on gitHub.

```
from atlassian import Insight
from config import Config     # modify this
import json
insight = Insight(
  url=Config.JSM_SERVER,
  username=Config.JSM_USER,
  password=Config.JSM_TOKEN,
  cloud=True
)

result = insight.list_object_schema()
print (json.dumps(result, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

However, not all functions are implemented. You have to patch them yourself.

Hope this can help you. :D

Comment: thanks @alexander. Does it work for bitbucket cloud ?

Comment: Yes, there are bitbucket components in the repo:
https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api/tree/master/atlassian/bitbucket

Comment: But  I think this repo is still under 3rd party developement. I would not suggest anyone to use this in production environment.